# How can i create an array that accepts user input from a a multiple textboxes and store it in a single array

Tags: c#

```
namespace DivingScorer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        double[] judgesScore;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void computeScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double degreeDifficulty;

            int scoreBox2;
            int scoreBox3;
            int scoreBox4;
            int scoreBox5;
            scoreBox2= Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            scoreBox3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            scoreBox4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            scoreBox5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);

            judgesScore[scoreBox2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            judgesScore[scoreBox3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            judgesScore[scoreBox4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            judgesScore[scoreBox5] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start from a tutorial here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you plan do with that array. Here is how you create an array with data from textboxes.

```
double[] judgesScore;
private void computeScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    judgesScore = new[]
    {
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text)
    };
}
```

I personally like using Generic List, unless I'm implementing very high efficiency algorithm.

```
IList<double> judgesScore;    
private void computeScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    judgesScore = new List<double>
    {
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text)
    };
}
```